# python memory leak listening to /dev/input

Tags: python, linux, barcode-scanner

This is a loop I'm using to listen in on a barcode scanner.
I have up to 8 instances of this program running at the same time one for each scanner. Although I'm getting the desired results for a while, each process eventually uses up a ton of cpu and memory. Any ideas why?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import os, sys
from evdev import InputDevice
from select import select
...
self.dev = InputDevice(self.devRoot + self.scanner['by-id'])
...

  def process(self):
    badge = ''
    while True:
      r,w,x = select([self.dev], [], [])
      try:
        for event in self.dev.read():

          if event.type == 1 and event.value != 4:

            if event.code < 11 and event.code > 0:
              # for numbers 1 to 9 
              code = event.code - 1
              badge = badge + str(code)

            elif event.code == 11:
              # for number 0
              badge = badge + '0'

            elif event.code == 28:
              theBadge = badge[::2].strip()
              if len(theBadge) == 5:
                fn = self.genFileName(theBadge)
                self.touch(fn)

              # reset the badge
              badge = ''

            else:
              # grab a letter or character from the key dictionary
              code = int(event.code)
              badge += self.deviceDict.keyDict[code]

      except Exception as e:
        continue
  def genFileName(self, badge):
    return str(self.scannerNum) + '-' + badge

  def touch(self, filename):
    TESTING = True
    if len(filename) <= 2:
      return 1

    filePath = self.scanDir + filename
    touchCommand = 'touch ' + filePath
    os.system(touchCommand)
    return
```

Comment: The only "strange" thing your code is doing is using `evdev`. Want to know where I've put money on?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to work around it.

Comment: I don't like the look of that continue in the except statement. Have you tried doing some sort of reporting - or even proper handling of exceptions - in your try-except when an exception occurs?

Comment: Barny is correct by pointing out the continue statement. The program needs to exit after a keyboardinterrupt, so i replaced the continue with a sys.exit(2) and I'm running the script in a bash while true loop. seems to work so far, will need to try it at work with all 8 scanners... thanks!

Comment: I see that you append to the string `badge` often. Sometimes it is supposed to be "reset", but my guess is that eventually that condition is not reached and the string keeps growing much larger than you expected. Possibly a series of unexpected events occur so you don't reach the reset condition, or possibly an exception is raised and your loop continues without resetting it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is not the case as the scanners I'm using append the carriage return character (28), thus triggering the reset. In any case, its been solved for now by exiting the program on interrupt and running it in a bash loop.